# access violation assigning a structure's element with a character pointed by a pointer

Tags: c

My question is: how to copy a character from a string pointed y a pointer to a character member of a structure. I got memory access violation error.

The following is a snippet of my code. Does anyone know the right way to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
struct machine_info {
  char id;
  int port;
} myInfo;


//part of a function
while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE, fh)!= NULL) {
    if(count ==0) {
      tmp = line;
      while(*tmp==' ')
        tmp++;

//myInfo->id=*tmp didn't work, so I tried to use strcpy, still didn't work
  strcpy(myInfo->id, *tmp); 
 // myInfo->id = *tmp;
} else if(count==1) {
  tmp = line;
  while(*tmp==' ')
    tmp++;
  end = tmp;
  while(*end != ' ')
    end++;
  *end = '\0';
  myInfo->port = atoi(tmp);  
  //
} else {
```

Comment: what data type is `tmp`?

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy(myInfo->id, *tmp);` is definitely wrong, `myInfo->id = *tmp;` should work (as long as `tmp` is `char*` type) unless either `myInfo` or `tmp` point at bad info. There's not quite enough code here to be sure, but my guess would be that `myInfo` is not initialized properly. Maybe it is `NULL`.

It might help to run the program in a debugger (you can compile with `-g` if using `gcc` to get better info`) to see exactly where it is failing and inspect the values of the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

myInfo is of type struct machine_info it is not pointer. To access the members you have use dot operator. myInfo.id = *tmp; if tmp is character pointer then it will work